# How to write a function to be used in a forEach statement to add all numbers in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have an exercise where I have to write my own forEach function which takes an array and a 'callback' function to add all the elements in the array.
So far I have this:

```
function forEachTest(arr, func){
    func(arr) // Simply apply the function to the array
}
```

However I don't know if this is the correct way a forEach call works.

Secondly, the said function to add the elements will therefore take the array and somehow add each element one by one till it reaches the end of the array and then console.log(result).

I tried using a variable to store the value but this doesn't work, I get NaN as a result.

```
function addEach(arr) {
    var sum;
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    console.log(sum);
}
```

The Nan happens when I call forEachTest(arr, addEach);

Note that arr is any array containing numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize the variable `sum = 0`.

```js
function forEachTest(arr, func) {
  func(arr);
}

function addEach(arr) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum += arr[i];
  }
  console.log(sum);
}

forEachTest([1,2,3], addEach);
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't been using JS for a long time, still getting used to the syntax. Will upvote if I can!

Answer (score 0):

What about this with initialization of your `sum` variable with `0` because inside your function it is initially `undefined`. So inside your loop it is executing like this way
`undefined=undefined+1`, `undefined=undefined+2` and so on which is `NaN` for every number of your array. Also I guess you're missing the `return` before your `func(arr);`

```js
function forEachTest(arr, func){
     return func(arr) // Simply apply the function to the array
}

function addEach(arr) {
    var sum=0;// see here
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
        //console.log(sum += arr[i]) //for debug purpose
    }
    //console.log(sum);
    return sum;
}

console.log(forEachTest([1,2,3,4,5],addEach))
```